# Deployment fails to jboss that uses oracle db, can't figure out why

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jboss, oracle11g

I am moving a Jboss quickstart from H1 database to Oracle 11g express. 
I have ensured that Jboss can connect to the Oracle db (test connection succesful). 
I am trying to deploy the project, I run:

```
mvn -X clean install jboss-as:deploy
```

But I get this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Fi
nal:deploy (default-cli) on project jboss-employee-rooster-jsp: Deployment faile
d and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
```

Not very descriptive. I don't know what causes it.
I suspect it must be the new datasource because the error started when I began to use oracle DS. Alternatively it might be something with `pom.xml` since I tampered with it a bit.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-employee-rooster-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.GA</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>employee-rooster-jsp</name>
    <description>employee-rooster-jsp</description>

    <url>localhost</url>
...etc
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.employeerooster.model.Member</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My file tree:
[picture](http://i.gyazo.com/c1cbb3ee62fc5f56280465f59b6e0294.png)

EDIT:
Here's what I found in the logs, but I still can't interpret how to fix it:

```
19:36:19,480 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jboss-employee-rooster-jsp.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jboss-employee-rooster-jsp.realm is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.servlet-security-quickstart]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"jboss-employee-rooster-jsp.war#primary\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.OracleDS]"
]}
```

Comment: checked log files of the server?

Comment: @khmarbaise found the logs, I will now add them to the question